# use rabbitmqadmin in docker

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, rabbitmqadmin

================Dockerfile1=================

```
FROM rabbitmq:3-management
MAINTAINER 123 "qyb1234@everbridge.com"
RUN apt-get update
ENV REFERSHED_AT 2015-07-20
RUN apt-get install -y python
ADD rabbitmqadmin /usr/local/bin/rabbitmqadmin
RUN chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/rabbitmqadmin
RUN service rabbitmq-server start && /usr/local/bin/rabbitmqadmin declare queue name=my-new-queue durable=true && service rabbitmq-server stop

RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable --offline rabbitmq_management
EXPOSE 15672
CMD rabbitmq-server
```

==============Dockerfile2===================

```
FROM rabbitmq:3-management
MAINTAINER 123 "qyb1234@gmail.com"
RUN apt-get update
ENV REFERSHED_AT 2015-07-20
RUN apt-get install -y python
ADD rabbitmqadmin /usr/local/bin/rabbitmqadmin
RUN chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/rabbitmqadmin
RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable --offline rabbitmq_management
EXPOSE 15672
CMD service rabbitmq-server start && /usr/local/bin/rabbitmqadmin declare queue name=my-new-queue durable=true && service rabbitmq-server stop && rabbitmq-server
```

The queue didn't declared when I use Dockerfile1, but Dockerfile2 works.What's the difference between Dockerfile1 and Dockerfile2?

Answer (score 6):

yes , there is difference in Dockerfile1 and Dockerfile2 . you are exposing port 15672 before queue creation in dockerfile2 and exposing after queue command in dockerfile1. 
Actually Rabbitmqadmin use HTTP API to create queue , exchange etc. if you apply command

```
curl -u guest:guest -XGET http://localhost:15672/api/queues
```

you will get list of all queues 
if you apply command :

```
curl -i -u guest:guest -H "content-type:application/json" \  
-XPUT -d'{"type":"direct","durable":true}' \
 http://localhost:15672/api/exchanges/%2f/my-new-exchange
```

it will create new exchange my-new-exchange. 
without exposing port how will you able to create queue ? . 
for more info you can go through manual of rabbitmq. 
http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/3646dee55e02/priv/www-api/help.html